# Cannot edit certain views once Fragment and ViewPager are implemented

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

**EDIT:**

From poking around more I'm almost positive that the problem is that when I inflate the layouts in my `FragmentActivity`'s onCreate() method, there are different views inflated within the ViewPager. So when I try to access them using the `xml1.findViewById()` its looking at a different View. How can I access the views that are being used in the `ViewPager`? Looking into my `FragmentPagerAdapter` it looks like the Fragments are created as new objects every time they are more than 1 swipe away. I want all 4 views to be intialized once. Then every time I call `updateUI` the four views are altered at once. So I can swipe between all four views with them newly updated.

I tried using `pagerAdapter.getItem(index).getView().findViewById( )`, but it returns a `NullPointerException`. After I got the exception, I tried overriding the `getView()` method in my `Fragment` classes. All I put in the method was `return view;`, where view was a saved instance of the View returned in the `onCreateView` method. This resulted in my ViewPager showing 4 blank screens to swipe between.

I added my `FragmentPagerAdapter` implementation to the bottom of the question.

**End Edit**

I tried to implement [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) by using `Fragments`. I am getting extremely strange results.

```
private TextView view1a, view1b;
private TextView view2a, view2b;
private TextView view3a, view3b;
private TextView view4a, view4b;
private Spinner spinner1, spinner2, spinner3, spinner4;
private Checkbox check1, check2, check3, check4;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private View xml1, xml2, xml3, xml4;

public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.main_page );

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.pager );
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MoreParmsFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MoreParmsFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

    xml1 = LayoutInflater.from( getBaseContext()).inflate( R.layout.xml1, null );
    xml2 = LayoutInflater.from( getBaseContext()).inflate( R.layout.xml2, null );
    xml3 = LayoutInflater.from( getBaseContext()).inflate( R.layout.xml3, null );
    xml4 = LayoutInflater.from( getBaseContext()).inflate( R.layout.xml4, null );
    populateSpinners();
    updateUI();
}


public void populateSpinners() {
    array1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, res.getStringArray( R.array.array1 )  );
    array1Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) xml1.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(array1Adapter);

    array2Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, res.getStringArray( R.array.array2 )  );
    array2Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) xml2.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(array2Adapter);

    array3Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, res.getStringArray( R.array.array3 )  );
    array3Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) xml3.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner3.setAdapter(array3Adapter);

    array4Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, res.getStringArray( R.array.array4 )  );
    array4Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) xml4.findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    spinner4.setAdapter(array4Adapter);
}

public void updateUI() {
    view1a = (TextView) xml1.findViewById( R.id.view_one_a );
    view1b = (TextView) xml1.findViewById( R.id.view_one_b );
    view2a = (TextView) xml2.findViewById( R.id.view_two_a );
    view2b = (TextView) xml2.findViewById( R.id.view_two_b );
    view3a = (TextView) xml3.findViewById( R.id.view_three_a );
    view3b = (TextView) xml3.findViewById( R.id.view_three_b );
    view4a = (TextView) xml4.findViewById( R.id.view_four_a );
    view4b = (TextView) xml4.findViewById( R.id.view_four_b );
    // There is work done here to determine what to set
    // the different TextViews' text to.
    //
    // `view**.setText()` is called for all views above with their respective values.

    spinner1 = (Spinner) xml1.findViewById( R.id.spinner1 );
    spinner2 = (Spinner) xml2.findViewById( R.id.spinner2 );
    spinner3 = (Spinner) xml3.findViewById( R.id.spinner3 );
    spinner4 = (Spinner) xml4.findViewById( R.id.spinner4 );
    // There is work done here to determine what index the Spinners
    // should have selected.
    //
    // `Spinner.setSelection( index ) is called on all spinners.

    check1 = (CheckBox) xml1.findViewById( R.id.check1 );
    check2 = (CheckBox) xml2.findViewById( R.id.check2 );
    check3 = (CheckBox) xml3.findViewById( R.id.check3 );
    check4 = (CheckBox) xml4.findViewById( R.id.check4 );
    // There is work done here to determine whether or not
    // to check the CheckBoxes.
    //
    // CheckBox.setChecked() is called for all checkboxes.
}
}
```

This is an example of my `Fragment` classes:

```
public class xmlOneFragment extends Fragment {
    int mCurrentPage;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
        Bundle data = getArguments();

        /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
        mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml1, container,false);
       return v;
    }
}
```

The **FIRST** problem is that the `Spinners` are never filled with their corresponding Arrays. There are `LogCat` calls throughout my `populateSpinners()` method that show me what I expect, but the `Spinners` themselves are not populated.

The **SECOND** problem arises in the `updateUI()` method. The comments below all of the `findViewById()` calls are where I do certain calculations to determine what text to put in the `TextViews`, what index to set the `Spinners` to, and whether or not to check the `CheckBoxes`. I have `LogCat` calls showing the values found, and they are all what is expected. 
When the `.setText(), .setSelection(), and .setChecked()` methods are called, no errors are shown, but none of the items are set at all. Everything stays blank.

The **THIRD** problem is what is confusing me the most. The `TextViews` now all have unique IDs. When I first tried implementing this `ViewPager`, I had the `updateUI()` method deal with TextViews without the `xml*.` prefix to the `findViewById()` calls.

```
view1a = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_one_a );
view1b = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_one_b );
view2a = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_two_a );
view2b = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_two_b );
view3a = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_three_a );
view3b = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_three_b );
view4a = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_four_a );
view4b = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_four_b );
// There is work done here to determine what to set
// the different TextViews' text to.
view**.setText( whatever );
```

This method resulted in a `NullPointerException`, but only when calling `.setText()` with the `TextViews` on the THIRD and FOURTH page. The first two pages did not throw any exceptions. So I commented out the third and fourth pages. The program ran and the first two pages showed the correct values in the correct TextViews. I then tried adding `xml*.` to the `findViewById()` methods, and now there are no exceptions thrown, but no Views are updated at all.

**Final Note:** The `ViewPager` functions correctly, and I can swipe between the proper layouts very nicely. The problems occur when I try to update the Views with the values I want. I am assuming the problem has something to do with how I am inflating the layouts, or how I do it too many times. The third problem really perplexes me. I cannot find any differences between the first/second page and the third/fourth page, but they are clearly acting differently. ALSO, the first code block shown is represented as an `Activity`, and the second code block I switched to a `FragmentActivity`.

**EDIT to add FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class MoreParmsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;

    public MoreParmsFragmentPagerAdapter( FragmentManager fm ) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem( int arg0 ) {
        if( arg0 == 0 ) {
            xmlOneFragment xml1Frag = new xmlOneFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt( "current_page", arg0 );
            xmlOneFrag.setArguments( data );
            return xmlOneFrag;
        } else if( arg0 == 1 ) {
            xmlTwoFragment xml2Frag = new xmlTwoFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt( "current_page", arg0 );
            xmlTwoFrag.setArguments( data );
            return xmlTwoFrag;
        } else if( arg0 == 2 ) {
            xmlThreeFragment xml3Frag = new xmlThreeFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt( "current_page", arg0 );
            xmlThreeFrag.setArguments( data );
            return xmlThreeFrag;
        } else {
            xmlFourFragment xml4Frag = new xmlFourFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt( "current_page",  arg0 );
            xmlFourFrag.setArguments( data );
            return xmlFourFrag;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if( position == 0 ) {
            return "xml1";
        } else if( position == 1 ){
            return "xml2";
        } else if( position == 2 ) {
            return "xml3";
        } else {
            return "xml4";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PAGE_COUNT;
}
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private MoreParmsFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
private FragmentManager fm;
private AntiPumpFragment apFrag;
private RelaxedCloseFragment relFrag;
private MiscParmsFragment miscFrag;
private DNP3Fragment dnpFrag;

public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.pager );
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    pagerAdapter = new MoreParmsFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);
    mViewPager.setAdapter( pagerAdapter );

    apFrag = (AntiPumpFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag( "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":0" );
    relFrag = (RelaxedCloseFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag( "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":1" );
    miscFrag = (MiscParmsFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag( "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":2" );
    dnpFrag = (DNP3Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag( "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":3" );
```

Everywhere in my code, all of these Fragments return null. The `ViewPager` shows correctly on my screen and I can swipe between all four views cleanly. However, all of my `if( apFrag != null )` statements are always skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The FIRST problem is that the Spinners are never filled with their
>   corresponding Arrays. There are LogCat calls throughout my
>   populateSpinners() method that show me what I expect, but the Spinners
>   themselves are not populated.

As you later figured it out you don't see the `Spinners` initialized because, instead of connecting to the views that come from the `Fragments` of the `ViewPager`, you simply use a `LayoutInflater` to inflate a **new view** from the layouts files used in the `Fragments`. Initializing this new view's children will not show any visual results because it doesn't exist/show in the UI of the `Activity`, it's "floating" around waiting for you to attach it to a `ViewGroup` in the `Activity` so it can show what views it has.

> The SECOND problem arises in the updateUI() method. The comments below
>   all of the findViewById() calls are where I do certain calculations to
>   determine what text to put in the TextViews, what index to set the
>   Spinners to, and whether or not to check the CheckBoxes. I have LogCat
>   calls showing the values found, and they are all what is expected.
>   When the .setText(), .setSelection(), and .setChecked() methods are
>   called, no errors are shown, but none of the items are set at all.
>   Everything stays blank.

It's the same point as one, you don't initialize the views that are show, you're updating an unattached `View` hierarchy.

> The THIRD problem is what is confusing me the most. The TextViews now
>   all have unique IDs. When I first tried implementing this ViewPager, I
>   had the updateUI() method deal with TextViews without the xml*. prefix
>   to the findViewById() calls.[...]This method resulted in a
>   NullPointerException, but only when calling .setText() with the
>   TextViews on the THIRD and FOURTH page. The first two pages did not
>   throw any exceptions

Maybe this will clear things out: The `ViewPager`, besides allowing swipeing left-right is also designed(through the adapter) to allow using as few views as possible(like a `ListView` for example, which inflates rows only for the visible rows). For this it only builds a certain number of pages. This number of pages is 3 by default(the one page that is visible + one on each side so the swipe will be smooth) and the `ViewPager` will start loading other pages as you swipe forward or backward. When you start the `ViewPager` it will load the first page(the visible one) + the next page(on the right) so the user can swipe right away. The other two pages aren't loaded for efficiency and trying to access widget from them will throw a `NullPointerException` as they can't be found. And, in the end you shouldn't do unnecessary work if the user might not see those pages at all. Now, you have the ability to modify the number of pages the `ViewPager` creates and keeps in memory(using the `setOffscreenPageLimit()` and supplying a number) but you should try to avoid it for efficiency as this will load all the widgets in the memory at once(in your case this will probably not be that bad, but I don't know what you want to do).

> I tried using pagerAdapter.getItem(index).getView().findViewById( ),
>   but it returns a NullPointerException. After I got the exception, I
>   tried overriding the getView() method in my Fragment classes. All I
>   put in the method was return view;, where view was a saved instance of
>   the View returned in the onCreateView method. This resulted in my
>   ViewPager showing 4 blank screens to swipe between.

You can't use the `geItem()` method of the adapter because this will not return the `Fragment`'s instance currently used by the `ViewPager`, it will return a **new** `Fragment` that is just instantiated. As it's just instantiated and not attached to the `Activity`, its `getView()` method will not return a view.

> How can I access the views that are being used in the ViewPager?

It depends when you want to access them. If the data will be available at the moment when you set the adapter on the `ViewPager` then simply move the initialization in the `Fragments` in the `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated` methods.

If you want to later access the `Fragment`'s from the `ViewPager` you could use a small hack , knowing that the `ViewPager` adds(for now) the `Fragments` in the `FragmentManager` with a special tag in the form of `android:switcher:theIdOfTheViewPager:thePositionInTheViewPager`. For example, to access the first `Fragment` of the `ViewPager`:

```
xmlOneFragment first = (xmlOneFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":0");
// if the fragment is found and its view is available do stuff
if (first != null && first.getView() != null) {
     // do stuff   
}
```

Not the optimal solution but it will work for you until you'll be more knowledgeable  about the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was extremely helpful. I tried `setOffScreenPageLimit()`, but it didn't work so I am going to go with the last suggestion you gave. I'm just wondering now, if I call this `findFragmentByTag` method in my `onCreate()` method, won't some Fragments not yet be loaded? Hence the `if statement`, I know, but is there a way to basically inflate the Fragments in my onCreate() so that there are 4 Fragments which the ViewPager uses over and over? No new instances?

Comment: @JuiCe Yes some fragments will not be loaded yet. You could avoid this by loading the data when you know that the target fragment is created(using for example a `OnPageChangeSelected` on the `ViewPager`). When you receive the `onPageSelected` look at the selected page and update the `Fragment` further. You could use a list of `Fragment` in the adapter for the `ViewPager`, but this will work until there is a configuration change, and you'll need to modify the adapter to take this in consideration so you always hold the proper fragment references(but this is another discussion).

Comment: @JuiCe But once again, loading data blindly in the `onCreate` isn't a good design and you should really let the fragments manage their data and the initialization process.

Comment: Thanks. I'll continue to mess around. I know its not a good design, but before I thought of implementing this `ViewPager`, I had everything working nice and clean so I'm scared to change it too much. What I posted is a very dumbed down version of the code, the class is 3000 lines long, but I will begin hacking away!

Comment: Hey I'm sorry but if you get a chance I still cannot get this to even start working. There is never a time in my code when calling `if( first!= null && first.getView() != null )` will ever succeed. All of the Fragments are ALWAYS ALL null. Even though they display on the screen and I can swipe through them cleanly.

Comment: @JuiCe *There is never a time in my code when calling...* _ If you try to work with the fragments in the `onCreate` yes those will be `null` because the fragments aren't created yet , this will happen after `onCreate` returns. Post a `Runnable` on one of the `Views` and try to access the fragments in the `Runnable`(`mViewPager.post(new Runnable() {...})`).